# how to interpret who clause?

Tags: clauses

When there is the word "and" before a who clause, should I interpret that the who clause applies to all the subjects before the clause or just to the one right before the clause? For example,

> We may disclose this to the following recipients: to our group companies, third party services providers and partners **who provide processing services to us.**

Does it mean

"to our group companies who provide processing services to us, third party services providers who provide processing services to us, and partners who provide processing services to us"

or

"to our group companies, third party services providers, and partners who provide processing services to us"?

Comment: I suspect it means the latter, or else they would have phrased it differently.

Comment: To clearly disambiguate, there needs to be rephrasing. 'We may disclose this to the following recipients, who all provide processing services to us: to our group companies, third party services providers, and partners.' // 'We may disclose this to the following recipients (but only those who provide processing services to us): our group companies, third party services providers, and partners.' //  'We may disclose this to the following recipients: to partners, who provide processing services to us; to our group companies, and to third party services providers.' //  ...

Comment: 'We may disclose this to the following recipients: to those partners who provide processing services to us, to our group companies, and to third party services providers.' // Of course, 'may' remains ambiguous.